# Absolute path with header location

Tags: php, absolute-path, document-root

abspath()

```
function abspath()
{
    echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

directory()

```
function directory()
{
    echo '/folder/';
}
```

Code Line:-

```
header('Location:'.abspath().directory());
```

Gives me the following as output:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/folder/
```

When I use

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];.directory());
```

It sends me to my index.php in **C:/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.php** 
Why its not working with functions?

I want to go to **C:/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.php** using this

```
header('Location:'.abspath().directory());
```

- Is there any problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your functions are `echo`ing your output and not returning it. You'll want to change your functions to:

```
function abspath()
{
    return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

function directory()
{
    return '/folder/';
}
```

So you can use the `return`ed value (namely `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or '/folder/', in this case) in your string concatentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Your path  should URI when using with header .

Soething like that

```
header('Location:http://yourpath.com/folder');
```

In the answer you are using a physical location where file residing

try `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`